# How to render react component after function call?

Tags: reactjs, antd

My goal show custom antd modal after function (`showCustomModal`) call (like [Modals.confirm](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001)).

CustomModal.tsx:

```
export function showCustomModal() {
  return <Modal>custom modal</Modal>
}
```

Component.tsx

```
import { showCustomModal } from 'CustomModal'

const Component= () => {
   
  const showModal = () => {
     showCustomModal()
  }

  return <button onClick={showModal}>show modal</button>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

React component at the end will need get called in return, here what you want do is use state to control when to show the component.

```
import { showCustomModal } from 'CustomModal'

const Component= () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={setShow(true)}>show modal</button>
      {show && <showCustomModal />}
    </>
  )
}
```